# Python: How to filter IDs that have Item D and any Item preceding D

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hi how do I filter VisitIDs that have Item D and **any** item **preceding** D.
Df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'VisitID':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4], 'Item':['A','B','C','D','A','D','B','B','C','D','C']})

VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
3       | B    |
3       | C    |
4       | D    |
4       | C    |
```

Expected Output:

```
VisitID | Item |
1       | A    |
1       | B    |
1       | C    |
1       | D    |
2       | A    |
2       | D    |
2       | B    |
```

VisitID 4 is excluded as it has an item proceeding D.

Comment: VisitID 2 also has an item preceeding D, isnt it?

Comment: yup for VisitID 2, A is preceding D. For VisitID 1, A,B,C is preceding D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First compare by `D` value by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) and then compare per groups all values with omit first one by position in [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) if exist at least one `True` by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
mask = df['Item'].eq('D').groupby(df['VisitID']).transform(lambda x: x.iloc[1:].any())
df = df[mask]
print (df)
   VisitID Item
0        1    A
1        1    B
2        1    C
3        1    D
4        2    A
5        2    D
6        2    B
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can check if the first element in the group is not `D` , then filter out groups which doesnot have any Item D in them:

```
c = df['Item'].eq('D').groupby(df['VisitID']).transform('any')
out = df[df.groupby('VisitID')['Item'].transform('first').ne('D') & c]
```

---

```
print(out)

   VisitID Item
0        1    A
1        1    B
2        1    C
3        1    D
4        2    A
5        2    D
6        2    B
```

Comment: may i know what is IIUC?

Comment: If I Understand Correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

Alternative using regex:

```
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'VisitID': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4],
    'Item':['A','B','C','D','A','D','B','B','C','D','C','E','F']
})
df

# Create pattern
p = r'[A-D]'

# Filter DataFrame based on pattern
df = df[~(df['VisitID'].isin(set(df[~df['Item'].str.contains(p)]['VisitID'])))]
df
```

[image]